# Displaying department_name in outer query - sql

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

i have this query

```
select last_name,job_id,department_id
from empl_demo
where (department_id) in 
(select department_id
from departments
where department_id=60);
```

my question is how can i display the "department_name" from the departments table?  for example :

```
select last_name,job_id,department_id,department_name
from empl_demo, departments;
```

but have it match my condition

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems `department_id` is a common attribute to both tables. So try using [JOINS](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/) like:

```
select A.last_name, A.job_id, B.department_id, B.department_name
from empl_demo A join departments B
on A.department_id=B.department_id
where B.department_id=60;
```

If you want to use subqueries then try:

```
select A.last_name, A.job_id, B.department_id, B.department_name
from (select * from empl_demo where department_id=60) A join 
(select * from departments where department_id=60) B
on A.department_id=B.department_id;
```

Comment: i did it using this way but i want to learn how to do it with subqueries

Comment: nevermind, thank you so much i solved it with squbqueries

Comment: If my answer is correct or was helpful then vote it up!

Answer (score 0):

Classic INNER Join, you really need to read some basics SQL courses (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/) for example.

```
SELECT e_d.last_name,
   e_d.job_id,
  e_d.department_id,
  d.department_name
FROM empl_demo e_d
INNER JOIN departments d on d.department_id = e_d.department_id
where department_id=60
```